# App Engine - using memcache when models have ReferenceProperties

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

In my App Engine app (in Python 2.7, threadsafe) I want to be able to display information on all entities of my ChildModel kind.  I think I've got memcache working, but because the ChildModel has a property that connects to a ParentModel there are some things happening that I don't understand.

I currently have the following models:

```
class ParentModel(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  # currently 109 of these

class ChildModel(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  parent_program = db.ReferenceProperty(ParentModel)
  # currently 758 of these
```

I'm implemented memcache using [the example from Nick Johnson's blog](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching).

```
class AllEntities(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    entitylist = deserialize_entities(memcache.get("entitylist"))
    if not entitylist:
      entitylist = ChildModel.all().fetch(None)
      memcache.set("entitylist", serialize_entities(entitylist))
    totalnum = ChildModel.all().count()
```

The very first time I run this I see the following in appstats:

```
datastore_v3.Get        758
datastore_v3.RunQuery   3
datastore_v3.Next       2
memcache.Get        1
memcache.Set        1
```

After that, I see the following in appstats:

```
datastore_v3.Get        758
datastore_v3.RunQuery   2
memcache.Get            1
```

It looks like memcache gets set correctly, based on the memcache size (1304599 byte(s)).  But I can't figure out how to stop the 758 datastore_v3.Get's which are extraordinary slow and also killing me on my quota of Datastore Small Operations and Datastore Read Operations.

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, count() is whats doing the 758 gets and cost you the small operation quota.

Since you have all the models loaded from memcache into a list you can just call `len(entitylist)` to get the amount of entities.

---

Try calling `prefetch_refprops(entitylist, ChildModel.parent_program)` prior to setting the value in the memcache [as describe in Nick's blog](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine).

Comment: Or just using len(entitylist)

Comment: @JesseRusak yeah, I tough the count() was for the other model :)

Comment: I don't think that's it. I just removed that section of code completely, and I still get 758 Gets. (Though it did remove one of the RunQuerys.) I still think it has something to do with the ReferenceProperty. I'd appreciate any ideas!

Comment: That worked!  I had to fiddle a little bit in order to get it to work when the values were already in memcache, but it's all set.  Took my datastore operations down by 20x... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would check your deserialize_entity function.  If its pulling in all of the child entities (reference property) then it will be doing it one at a time (hence lots of gets).

If you want the referenced entities prefetch them with a batched get - have a look at Nick Johnsons prefetch_refprop blog article.

Or modify the deserialize_entities to not fetch the reference properties if you don't need them

Comment: you mean deserialize_entities, serialize_entities entities is not called the second time.